# Path for storing the 'per machine' application details

Tags: .net, path, clickonce, application-data

My application needs to write some information to a file and keep it common to the machine(common to all users).

Currently I stored it in **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data**

But the problem is whenever the file is created by admin all the other users doesn't have **write** permission to it.

But I want write permission to the file for all users, so that all the users can modify data in it. Could any one help me in this?

**EDIT:** I want a store an xml file that is common to all users.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

will the registry be a good place for you? (depends what you want to store).
you can create a node on the HKLM hive to be accessed by all users

Comment: No it wont be, I want to store an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you study the [`File.SetAccessControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol) method and [`FileSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity) class.  In particular, the [`FileSecurity` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity) provides a complete example of modifying the file access control list (permissions set) for a given file. Here is a simplified version of that example, which gives everyone read and write permission for `C:\TEMP\junk.txt`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

class WorldWrite
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string filename = @"C:\TEMP\junk.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(filename)) {
            Console.WriteLine("No such file " + filename);
            return;
        }

        /* Get the previous ACL, add a rule to give everyone read
         * and write permission, and write back the resulting ACL. */
        FileSecurity fileACLs = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
        fileACLs.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
            // For everyone 
            new SecurityIdentifier (
                WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, 
                null /* domain SID; ignored for Everyone */
            ),
            // Allow read and write (of data and metadata), 
            // but not delete or execute
            FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.Write,
            AccessControlType.Allow
        ));
        File.SetAccessControl(filename, fileACLs);
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
}
```

I'm also concerned about how you are specifying the shared application data directory. If you're hard-coding the name `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data`, then your code won't work on non-English versions of Windows, or Vista or Windows 7 for that matter. It may be better to use the [`SpecialFolder` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder) to find the right directory to use.

Comment: I have already tried this, but the problem is only the owner of the file will be able to change access of the file.

So I am planning to change write access to user group 'Everyone' as soon as it is created for the first time.

Anyhow thanks for your answer!

Comment: Wait, so you needed someone *other* than the file owner to change its permissions?! I hope you understand why only trusted users (such as admins!) normally have that right...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ClickOnce deployment, this will be difficult to do, because you have to elevate privileges in order to read/write to a common folder, and ClickOnce apps won't do that.

You could create a small exe file that does what you want, and have the clickonce application invoke that and let it elevate privileges. That's about the only option you have.

Comment: I have fixed it by granting write permission to everyone while creating the file for the first time.. Now the other users are able to modify the file :)

Comment: So are you manually creating the file? Or are you doing it from the ClickOnce app, and if so, how?

Comment: But how did you grant write permission to everyone? Did you do that programmatically or manually?

Comment: In the ClickOnce app? It let you create the folder and give write permission to everyone when you created it? I get this question a lot, so it's great if that's how you got it to work, and I can recommend the same solution to others.

Comment: This would help you I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533433/creating-xml-file-with-write-access-given-to-all-the-windows-account-users