# App unable to rewrite file saved by a Windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, programdata

The problem is, my .NET Windows Service (running under `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`) creates a file in a folder inside `ProgramData`, and the windows application gets a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` if it tries to overwrite it. Currently logged in user has an admin account, but the app doesn't start elevated (and I would like to avoid it).

If the service starts after the application, then the file is created by the UI app and it works fine. Is it possible to make a .NET Windows Service create a file which can be overwritten by a Windows app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just about file permissions. You need to add write entry for the users you want to be able to run the application. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx) on how to set it.

The key part:

```
// Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
// current security settings.
FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
                rights, controlType));

// Set the new access settings.
File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful! But I tried to add access control to Everyone as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6533772/1488067), and it fails inside my win app (service does it without problems). Should I only set permissions in the service app?

Comment: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation, at `System.IO.File.SetAccessControl`. But the service does it without problems, and writing then works without problem. But since this code is shared between both apps, I guess I have to check who's running it before trying to set access control (it's only needed if win service is creating the file). Does that make sense?

Comment: It means that the user you run application under doesn't have sufficient rights to change file permissions. Then what you say will solve it.